# Remove or override request interceptor for scoped configuration in Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular to handle my token/header authentication in a single page Angular web application.
Using addFullRequestInterceptor, I set the correct headers for each outgoing REST API call, using a personal key for encrypting data.

```
Restangular
        .setBaseUrl(CONSTANTS.API_URL)
        .setRequestSuffix('.json')
        .setDefaultHeaders({'X-MyApp-ApiKey': CONSTANTS.API_KEY})
        .addFullRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
        .addErrorInterceptor(errorInterceptor);

function requestInterceptor(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
        var timeStamp = Helpers.generateTimestamp(),
            //Condensed code for illustration purposes
            authSign = Helpers.generateAuthenticationHash(hashIngredients, key, token),
            allHeaders = angular.extend(headers, {
                'X-MyApp-Timestamp': timeStamp,
                'Authentication': authSign
            });

        return {
            headers: allHeaders
        }
    }
```

Works great. There is one exception I need though: For a new visitor that has not logged in yet, a generic key/token pair is requested via REST. This key/token pair is used in the headers of the login authentication call.
So for this call, I create a separate Restangular sub-configuration. In this configuration I want to override the requestInterceptor. But this seems to be ignored (i.e. the original interceptor is still called). It doesn't matter if I pass null or a function that returns an empty object.

```
var specialRestInst = Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
                RestangularConfigurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(function() {return {}});
            }),
            timeStamp = Helpers.generateTimestamp(),
            header = {'X-MyApp-Timestamp': timeStamp};

        specialRestInst.one('initialise').get({id: 'app'}, header)
```

So as documented by Restangular, withConfig takes the base confuration and extends it. I would like to know how to removeFullRequestInterceptor (this function does not exist), override it, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach and try to pass a flag to the interceptor. If the flag exists then the `authSign` is excluded. You can do this using `withHttpConfig`. It's better to exclude on special cases then to always having to tell the interceptor to include the `authSign`.

So you would update the interceptor like this.

```
function requestInterceptor(element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {
    var timeStamp = Helpers.generateTimestamp();
    var allHeaders = {'X-MyApp-Timestamp': timeStamp};
    if(!httpConfig.excludeAuth) {
        //Condensed code for illustration purposes
        var authSign = Helpers.generateAuthenticationHash(hashIngredients, key, token);
        allHeaders['Authentication'] = authSign;
    }
    return angular.extend(headers, allHeaders);
}
```

When you need to exclude the `authSign` you would use restangular like this.

```
specialRestInst.withHttpConfig({excludeAuth: true}).get({id: 'app'});
```

You should be able to add any values to http config you want as a long as they aren't already used.

I'm not sure if this will work as expected, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: That is an option I guess. I already managed to work around the issue by detecting what the `route`-parameter is. But if it is possible to make sub-configurations, I would expect that interceptors can be overridden. So I'm hoping someone knows how (or knows why it's impossible).